# Installing Rostlab's PredictProtein

Tags: proteins, software-installation, linux

I am trying to install Rostlab's PredictProtein in a Virtual Machine as detailed here https://rostlab.org/owiki/index.php/How_to_Run_The_PredictProtein_Machine_Image_with_VirtualBox:

> 1. [Download PredictProtein Machine Image](http://rostlab.org/services/ppmi/) to your local drive. You will need the [Bio-Linux](http://nebc.nerc.ac.uk/tools/bio-linux/bio-linux-6.0)-based 'VMWARE/VMDK' format version.
>
>    - Choose the Debian-based version in case you do not need a graphical
>        user interface. This image is only half the size of the
>        Bio-Linux-based image.
> 2. Download a [database image](http://rostlab.org/services/ppmi/) to your local drive. We recommend the 'raw' format version.
> 3. Create New Virtual Machine: Machine -> New
> 4. Name your virtual machine as 'PredictProtein'
> 5. Choose Linux and Debian as operation system
> 6. Locate and select the VMware .vmdk file as your boot disk
> 7. Give at least 2GB of RAM to your virtual machine
> 8. Click 'Finish'
> 9. Boot your new virtual machine.
> 10. If the message "The disk drive for /mnt/local-storage is not ready yet or not present" appears, press 's'.

The problem comes at this step:

> 11. Open a terminal and enter:
>
>     ```
>     sudo mkfs.ext4 -F -m 0 -L local-storage /dev/sdb
>     sudo mount -a
>     sudo mkdir /mnt/local-storage/rostlab-data && cd /mnt/local-storage/rostlab-data
>     sudo mount -a
>     sudo mount /mnt/rostlab-data
>     sudo tar -xvJf /mnt/rostlab-data/rostlab-data.txz
>     sudo umount /mnt/rostlab-data && cd
>     ```

When I run `sudo mount /mnt/rostlab-data`, I get:

```
mount: special device LABEL=rostlab-data does not exist
```

How should I proceed?

Additional notes -

The output for

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

is

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0   0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=9a9418ff-48f9-421a-b25a-82161839351d / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=a96757f4-8cc7-410f-95ee-b5ae642eb9ed none swap sw  0       0

LABEL=local-storage /mnt/local-storage auto defaults,nofail 0   2
LABEL=rostlab-data /mnt/rostlab-data auto defaults,noauto,ro 0  0

/mnt/local-storage/rostlab-data /usr/share/rostlab-data none bind,nofail 0 0
```

The output for

```
blkid
```

is

```
/dev/ramzswap0: TYPE="swap"
/dev/sda1: UUID="9a9418ff-48f9-421a-b25a-82161839351d" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda5: UUID="a96757f4-8cc7-410f-95ee-b5ae642eb9ed" TYPE="swap"
/dev/sdb: LABEL="local-storage" UUID="df841028-8dd1-4cd2-b1bb-6ae1f6887510" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Sounds like they've misconfigured the image. Please [edit] your question and post the output of running `cat /etc/fstab` and `blkid` from the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the image you downloaded is missing the partition with the label `rostlab-data`. Your `blkid` output shows that you have the `local-storage` partition, but not the `rostlab-data` which is automatically added to your `/etc/fstab`.

I am afraid you'll have to contact the developers and let them know. Sounds like a bug.